# mule maven dependency issue

Tags: maven, mule

I have an existing api which i need to work on . ( Mule 3 )
when I try and do a `mvn clean install` it fails with this error:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency- 
    plugin:2.10:unpack (unpack) on project xyz: Unable to resolve artifact.: 
    Could not transfer artifact ORGID:xyz:zip:fat-raml:1.0.2 from/to 
    springio (http://repo.spring.io/libs-release): Failed to transfer file: 
    http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/ORGID/xyz/1.0.2/xyz-1.0.2-fat-raml.zip. 
    Return code is: 308 , ReasonPhrase:Permanent Redirect.
    [ERROR]   ORGID:xyz:zip:1.0.2
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
    [ERROR]   MuleRepositoryEE (https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus- 
    ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/, releases=true, snapshots=false),
    [ERROR]   MuleRepository 
    (https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/, releases=true, 
    snapshots=false),
    [ERROR]   AnypointExchangeRepository 
    (https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v2/organizations/ORGID/maven, releases=true, 
    snapshots=true),
    [ERROR]   springio (http://repo.spring.io/libs-release, releases=true, snapshots=true),
    [ERROR]   Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, releases=true, snapshots=true),
    [ERROR]   mulesoft-releases (http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/, releases=true, 
    snapshots=true),
    [ERROR]   mule-ee-releases (https://repository- 
    master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/, releases=true, 
    snapshots=true),
    [ERROR]   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

The relevant plugin is :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>ORGID</groupId>
                                <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0.2</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                                <classifier>fat-raml</classifier>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>src/main/api/</outputDirectory>
                                <includes>**/*</includes>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The repository section in pom is :

```
<repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>springio</id>
         <name>springio</name>
         <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
         <layout>default</layout>
      </repository>
     
      <repository>
        <id>Central</id>
        <name>Central</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
     
    <repository>
        <id>AnypointExchangeRepository</id>
        <name>AnypointExchangeRepository</name>
        <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v2/organizations/ORGID/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mule-ee-releases</id>
        <name>MuleEE Releases Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases- 
ee/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-release</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>AnypointExchangeRepository</id>
        <name>AnypointExchangeRepository</name>
        <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/ORGID/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I am not sure why maven is trying to find raml in spring repository ? when it should find it in the ORGID repo ?
Does the order of the repositories need to change ?

Answer (score 1):

The permanent redirect error may be caused because some of the repositories are being defined in you pom with HTTP URLs (ie `http://...`). Most repositories these days use HTTPS because of security reasons and redirect the HTTP requests. If Maven doesn't follow redirects it fails the build. Try using HTTPS URLs for all the repositories.